# Designing RESTful shopping cart

Tags: rest, ember.js, single-page-application

I am building a single page application for booking hotel conference rooms and am not sure how to set it up, or even if RESTful is the proper approach.  There will be four steps to this SPA:

1. The user chooses a date (available dates come from server - some days could be fully booked).
2. The user chooses a conference room (conference rooms available at this hotel on the date chosen in step 1 are retrieved from the server).
3. The user enters their name, address, billing info.
4. User sees confirmation page.

This same SPA will be used by multiple hotels with the same database back-end, and for the front-end I was thinking Ember.

Is RESTful the right approach for this application?

I was thinking:

GET /dates?hotel_id=xxx (should I pass the hotel ID in the URL vs. in headers vs. in the body?)

GET /rooms?hotel_id=xxx&date=yyy (should I be passing the date and hotel_id in, or somehow remember it on the server?)

POST /order with body: {date, conference_room_id, name/address/billing info}, returns { confirmation_id }

Should the name/address/billing info be put into a separate POST?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a REST(ful) framework there's no concept of session. Every request must send all the required information in order to identify a resource.
I'll post an example below, based on requirements you provided.

**GET** `/hotels/{hotel_id}/dates`

Path params:

- `hotel_id` (*required*)

Query params:

- `startDate` (*optional*, default: today)
- `endDate` (*optional*, default (example): today + 3 months)
- `status` (*optional*, `"available"/"booked"/"all"`, default: `"all"`)

Response body: `[{"id":"20160503", "dateStr":"May 5th 2016", "status": "available"}]`

**GET** `/hotels/{hotel_id}/dates/{date_id}/rooms`

Path params:

- `hotel_id` (*required*)
- `date_id` (*required*)

Query params:

- `status` (*optional*, `"booked"/"available"/"all"`, default:`"all"`)

Response body: `[{"id": "12", "status": "available", "reservationId": ""}, {"id: "13", "status": "booked", "reservationId" : "123"}]`

Note: this kind of implementation allows to list different combinations of dates and rooms (e.g. booked rooms in available days).

**POST** `/hotels/{hotel_id}/reservations`

Path params:

- `hotel_id`(*required*)

Request body: `{"dateId":"20160503", "roomId":"12", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "address": "xxx", "vatNumber" : "yyy", "companyName": "zzz"}`

Note: if you store billing addresses as separate entities (e.g. if your server is required to "remember" them), then it can be useful to implement POST and GET services for billing addresses (`/billing`) and refer to them with proper identifiers.

Response body: `{"reservationId" : "324"}`

**GET** `/hotels/{hotel_id}/reservations/{reservation_id}`

Path params:

- `hotel_id`(*required*)
- `reservation_id` (*required*)

Response body: `{"dateId":"20160503", "roomId":"12", "firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "address": "xxx", "vatNumber" : "yyy", "companyName": "zzz"}` (same as POST request body)

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me develop a solution.

Answer (score 0):

GET /dates?hotel_id=xxx (should I pass the hotel ID in the URL vs. in headers vs. in the body?)

GET /rooms?hotel_id=xxx&date=yyy (should I be passing the date and hotel_id in, or somehow remember it on the server?)

POST /order with body: {date, conference_room_id, name/address/billing info}, returns { confirmation_id }

Your solution can use Restful API approach. Because it enable any other component to directly call your APIs. It can be APP, or a website or plugin or just another java program connected to internet, they just need to trigger your API and they are done.

URL you mentioned for your application, please note that one should use resource-based URL approach while building RESTful api.

GET /date/hotels/ -> Gives you all available rooms in all hotels on that particular day
GET /dates/hotels/ -> Give you list of available rooms for a particular hotel (Use dates/hotel_id instead of dates/?hotel_id=xxx). Parameter should be used to filter your result. E.g. dates/hotels/hotel_id?PIN=142: This should gives you hotel whose pin matches 142
dates/hotels?MAX_RECORD=50: This should give you list of hotels but limit to 50

You can find more about creating resource-based Restful API https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn

Answer (score 0):

I would put the "Selects" into GETs as designed.
e.g. dates GET /hotel/:id/date -> Get all available dates
     rooms GET /hotel/:id/date/:date/rooms -> Get all available rooms

per design in a RESTful API GET is defined for requesting data.
For the POST I would not breakdown into a seperate POST but you can put some parameter like hotel_id or date into the URL.

Best
Fabian